# Cannot displaying MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

I tried below [tutorial MapView.](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/part_2_-_maps_api)

I have added

1) Mono, Android.Googlemaps.

2) using Android.Locations;

3) implemented :  public class Activity1 : MapActivity

These are the error Messages :

> Error CS0115: 'MapView.Activity1.IsRouteDisplayed': no suitable method found to override (CS0115) (MapView)
>
> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MapActivity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an        assembly
>   reference?) (CS0246) (MapView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:apiKey="my google map key here" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`[Activity (Label = "MapView", MainLauncher = true)]`

```
public class Activity1 : MapActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);  
    }

    protected override bool IsRouteDisplayed 
    {
        get 
    {
            return false;              
    }
    }
}
```

Would appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Google Map V1 is deprciated. You should use [Android Google Map V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) . Thanks

Comment: @captaindroid: Thanks. I followed http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/part_2_-_maps_api, use Adroid SDK Manager to install google api ( Level 14 and above) and created AVD and added reference. Am I doing it right? Still get error. PLease help.

Comment: Check and use the correct AVD, now the error msg is : Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MapActivity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (MapView) What this means?

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have already mentioned, Google maps v1 is no longer available for new apps.

Instead you must use v2 from Google play services.

It`s not entirely straightforward to use v2 - the Google licensing makes it hard to redistribute the Google play components, but there is [a tutorial](https://github.com/xamarin/mini-hacks/tree/master/GoogleMaps) which works.